# Automatize method calling c++

Tags: c++11, function-pointers, std-pair

I am working on C++11 application. There I have a method which will be called many times(1000). That method accepts as parameters string and pointer to function.

The thing is that pointer to function will take different type of arguments, sometimes int, sometimes std:string and so on.

In order to avoid having 1000 different calls to my method I have thoguth of building a list of std::pairs with string and pointer to functions and iterating throught it to call my method.

But I have not found a clean way to achieve that.

example:

```
// This is the method I want to call, 
// T is function pointer, I have several versions for
// different data types, e.g here bool version
template <class T>
void myMethod(const std::string& strArg,
              void (T::*setter) (const bool)) const
```

Previous method will be called 1000 times with different arguments: each strings corresponds to unique function pointer.

Now I am calling it 1000 times like:

```
myMethod(str1, pFunction1);
myMethod(str2, pFunction2);
myMethod(str3, pFunction3);
...
myMethod(str1000, pFunction1000);
```

I would like to, first create a list filled by me manually:

```
std::list<std::pair<str, functionPointer>>
```

Then I would iterate calling my method for each member in the list

Any ideas, please?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do. Can you edit some examples into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a collection of such pairs.

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void (SomeClass::*) (const bool)>> myMethodArgs 
{
    { str1, pFunction1 },
    { str2, pFunction2 },
    ...
    { str1000, pFunction1000 },
};
```

And then call them all

```
for (auto & pair : myMethodArgs)
{
     myMethod(pair.first, pair.second); // deduces myMethod<SomeClass>
}
```

But it sounds like you have different types for many of these calls. You could instead have a collection of `std::function<void()>`s made from lambdas, with each a different instantiation of `myMethod`

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> myMethodCalls
{
    []{ myMethod(str1, &Class1::method); },
    []{ myMethod(str2, &Class2::other_method); },
    ...
    []{ myMethod(str1000, &Class1000::final_method); },
};

for (auto & call : myMethodCalls)
{
    call();
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point here: the function signatures are not `void (SomeClass::*) (const bool)`; they're not even identical.

Comment: @MSalters yes, that's what the second half of the answer explains

Comment: Fair point. I overlooked the fact that the caller already seems to have a way to come up with the missing `Class1` through `Class1000` objects. Normally when you bind a member function call through a lambda, you need an object to call that member function on. This case seems different in that `myMethod` somehow comes up with the 1000 missing objects.

Comment: @MSalters *allegedly* somehow comes up with the 1000 missing objects :p

Answer (score 2):

I would like you to the point when you want to call your function later!

Lets assume we can write the code you want like ( pseudo-code ):

```
std::list<std::pair<str, PointerToFunctionWithAnySignature >> ptrList;
```

now you fill up the list

```
ptrList.add( "bla", Do1 );
ptrList.add( "blub", Do2 );
```

and the signature of the functions is like:

```
void Do1(int);
void Do2(float, std::string& );
```

Now you want to loop over the list:

```
for ( auto& el: ptrList )
{
    // here we want to call the function:
    el.second( ???????? );
}
```

That's the question! If you have different signatures: How do you want to know which parameter you have to fill on which position in that call.

As a result, even if you are able to store pointers to functions with different signatures, it makes no sense because you can't call them!

If you are already know the parameters for the later call, you can use `lambda functions` to store the function and the parameters as a single object and make it callable with a unique signature. You can also use std::bind for that, but lambda is preferred, easier to handle and simpler to read.